# How to separate the latest file from Multiple files in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have 5000 files in a folder and on daily basis new file keep loaded in same  file. I need to get the latest file only on daily basis among all the files.

Will it be possible to  achieve the scenario in Mule out of box.

Tried keeping file component inside Poll component( To make use of waterMark) but not working.

Is there any way we can achieve this. If not please suggest the best way ( Any possible links).

Mule Studio: 5.3, RunTime 3.7.2.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Not really any extremely quick out of the box solution. But there are other ways. Im not saying this is the right or only way of solving it, but I've earlier implemented a similar scenario in this way:

A Normal File inbound with a database table as file-log. Each time a new file is processed, a component checks if its name appears in the table. By choice or filter I only continue if it isn't in there already - and after processing I add the filename to the table.

This is a quite "heavy" solution though. A simpler access would be to use an idempotent filter with a object store. For example a Redis server: https://github.com/mulesoft/redis-connector/blob/master/src/test/resources/redis-objectstore-tests-config.xml

Comment: Thanks for your command. My project doesn't involve DB Table w.r.t  related with this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually very simple if your incoming file contains timestamp........you can configure the file inbound connector by setting file:filename-regex-filter pattern="myfilename_#[function:timestamp].csv". I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks.  For example: If i want to process the files which is generated only today ( example 10 files). How do i specify the filter pattern of today alone. If it comes tomorrow, then  code need to change, to tomorrow date automatically. If possible could you please post the script.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use a quartz scheduler( mention the time in cron expression), followed by a groovy script in which you can start the file connector . Keep the file connector in another flow.